# Use of Init in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a specific use of init() method in javascript?

Consider

```
var obj = {
    init: function(){
      return "Hello World";
   },
   foo: function(){
       return "Foo";
   }
}
```

Is there a difference between `obj.init()` v/s `obj.foo()`? Is it just a naming convention? Renaming init to `main()` has no effect.  I realize that `init` is a naming convention that is used to place all of the initialization code for the object. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: Are you trying to implement some class-object-constructer stuff in Javascript? If so, I could post some sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init` has no special meaning in Javascript. It is just an ordinary valid identifier, like `foo`.

It is often used instead of `initialize`, because most developers know that `init` means initialize, and it's shorter to type. If you prefer, there would be no problems with using `initialize` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Init has no special meaning in javascript. If you're looking for a constructor, in javascript you can call a function with the new keyword.  This will create a 'new' this object and pass it to that function as the scope.

```
function obj(){
    this.foo = function() { 
       return "foo";
    }
}

var o = new obj(); // o.foo() returns "foo"
```

a lot of time people will use an init function to encapsulate the constructor functionality.  It is common practice to also write an init function for setting up a plain object when you're not using a constructor.